# Search for and download a specific file that is in one of multiple directories

Tags: linux, bash, http, wget

I'm trying to have WGET download the specific file called `5200r.img`. The file is in one of three directories located at the following address:

```
https://pds-imaging.jpl.nasa.gov/data/galileo/galileo_orbiter/go_0020/e14/europa/
```

The directories are `c044094`, `c044095`, and `c044098`.

How do I ask WGET to search each of these three directories for the `5200r.img` and download it?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

address='https://pds-imaging.jpl.nasa.gov/data/galileo/galileo_orbiter/go_0020/e14/europa'
possibilities=( c044094 c044095 c044098 )
file='5200r.img'

for possibility in "${possibilities[@]}"
do
   wget "$address/$possibility/$file" && break
done
```

The script will build full URLs and try them one by one. The first successful download will exit (`break`) the loop.

---

You tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) so I used an array to store possibilities. More portable version could be:

```
#!/bin/sh

address='https://pds-imaging.jpl.nasa.gov/data/galileo/galileo_orbiter/go_0020/e14/europa'
possibilities="c044094 c044095 c044098"
file='5200r.img'

for possibility in $possibilities
do
   wget "$address/$possibility/$file" && break
done
```

It works because word splitting and pathname expansion on `$possibilities` generate what you want; but this is only because your possibilities are "nice enough". In general (forget about URLs) you may want to deal with possibilities containing `*`, `?`, spaces, quotes etc. This code

```
possibilities='/etc/* "two words" foo'
for possibility in $possibilities
do …
```

will expand `/etc/*` and use `"two` and `words"` separately. Often this is not what you want. An array in Bash is very good in such case. If you ever need a solution for `sh` (which has no concept of arrays), consider this approach:

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r possibility; do
   printf '%s\n' "$possibility"
   # or whatever you want to do
done << EOF
/etc/*
*.???
multiple words   with spaces
   leading spaces
" quotes '
EOF
```

---

In the above snippets `5200r.img` is hardcoded. Use `file="$1"` instead of `file='5200r.img'`, so you can download other files in a convenient way, like this:

```
./name_of_script 4852r.img
```